# Stream not closing appropriately while using named pipes in Java/Linux

Tags: java, linux, process, named-pipes

I have a program where I use named pipes to share info with an external executable:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mkfifo /tmp/myfifo");
p.waitFor();
Process cat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /tmp/myfifo");
BufferedWriter fifo = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/myfifo")));
fifo.write("Hello!\n");
fifo.close();
cat.waitFor();
```

When I execute this, the program hangs waiting for `cat` to finish. It seems that cat has not 'realized' that the fifo was closed.

I tried running `$> touch /tmp/myfifo` on the terminal, and it worked to 'unhang' the process and it finishing properly; but when I added code to run this within my program, it would remain hanging:

```
fifo.close();
Process touch = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("touch /tmp/myfifo");
touch.waitFor();
cat.waitFor();
```

The process will still hang waiting for `cat` to finish. I'm not sure what to do now.

**NOTE** - I have already added code to consume the output of the `cat` command, but the problem does not seem to be there.

Anyone know a workaround/fix for this?

Comment: Looks like you're not consuming the output of `cat`, which might be the problem.

Comment: If that were the problem, wouldn't the process remain hanging after running `$> touch /tmp/myfifo` on the terminal?

Comment: Not sure why the `touch` unsticks your `cat` process TBH.

Comment: FWIW when I try the exact same code, it works fine. `cat` does not block.

Comment: that's quite strange. In any case, thank you.

Comment: Because `touch` causes the `cat` process to close, my guess is that your program isn't actually opening the fifo. I.e. this line: `BufferedWriter fifo = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/myfifo")));` - isn't doing what you want it to. Are you sure it's not throwing an exception? If it definitely progresses, it seems like it's somehow opening the wrong file. Try running under `ptrace` to see what is happening at the system call level.

Comment: I have debugged this extensively. The `cat` freezes waiting for more data.

Answer (score 1):

> some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard
>   input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream
>   or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess
>   to block, and even deadlock.you need to consume the output like print it on stdout something or file

try something like this

```
 Process cat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /tmp/myfifo");
 new Thread(new Reader(cat.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
 new Thread(new Reader(cat.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
 int returnCode = cat.waitFor();
 System.out.println("Return code = " + returnCode);


class Reader implements Runnable
{
public Reader (InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
      this.istrm = istrm;
      this.ostrm = ostrm;
  }
  public void run() {
      try
      {
          final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          for (int length = 0; (length = istrm.read(buffer)) != -1; )
          {
              ostrm.write(buffer, 0, length);
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  private final OutputStream ostrm;
  private final InputStream istrm;
}
```

Comment: I am receiving NullPointer exceptions from istrm.read(buffer))

Comment: I'm getting NullPointerException from the line with `istrm.read(buffer))`. For both streams. Is there  a reason why they would return Nulls?

Comment: the program runs, and  remains frozen, so there's no return code - even if I run that cat con the console, it will freeze until someone 'closes' the named pipe - with `touch` or `echo` or anything.

Comment: try "/bin/cat" instead of just cat

Comment: the 'final' fixed it, somehow : ) -  but the process is still hanging at the end

Comment: I am using your class in a larger project. But the main points are the ones you see.

Comment: you can should accept the answer or put appropriate comment so that other can get better idea if someone stucked in same problem

Comment: The process will still hang until I run `touch /tmp/myfifo` manually, on the console. Any other ideas?